# Get project's gravity value in Godot

Tags: physics, godot, gdscript

I need to get access project's gravity value which set in Project Settings -> Physics -> 3D -> Gravity, however I couldn't find any related information about this.

How do I get project's gravity value in GDScript? In Unity, it can be done by simply Physics.gravity, but in Godot, couldn't find similar.

Using Godot 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all project settings through the [`ProjectSettings`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_projectsettings.html#class-projectsettings-physics-3d-default-gravity) object.

Note that the *effective gravity* on an object may be different from this value, as `Areas` can override gravity.
You can access the gravity affecting an object at a given point in time via [`PhysicsDirectBodyState.total_gravity`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_physicsdirectbodystate.html#class-physicsdirectbodystate-property-total-gravity). `PhysicsDirectBodyState` can be accessed from [`_integrate_forces`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-method-integrate-forces) as well as some physics-related callbacks.